# HTML file maker demo givers error

Tags: asp.net

Here is my code
it works properly any body can guide me how to improve this code to make better HTML file to be used in CMS application

Please create folder named "Images"
TO working properly

Generated HTML file will be stored at Project Folder

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HTMLMaker.aspx.cs" Inherits="HTML5Demo.HTMLMaker" ValidateRequest="false"  %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b>HTML Maker</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label Text="Title" ID="lblTitle" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label Text="Image" ID="lblImage" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fluImage" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label Text="Description" ID="lblDescription" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="25"
                            Rows="5" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**.cs file**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

 public partial class HTMLMaker : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ImagePath = string.Empty;
            string ImageName = string.Empty;
            string FileName = Server.MapPath("~/") + txtTitle.Text + ".html";
            if (fluImage.HasFile)
            {
                ImageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + Path.GetExtension(fluImage.FileName);
                ImagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + ImageName;
                fluImage.SaveAs(ImagePath);
            }

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                    w.WriteLine("<html lang=\"en\">");
                    w.WriteLine("<head>");
                    w.WriteLine("<title>" + txtTitle.Text + "</title>");
                    w.WriteLine("</head>");
                    w.WriteLine("<body>");
                    w.WriteLine("<div>");
                    w.WriteLine("<img src='Images/" + ImageName + "' alt=" + fluImage.FileName + "  />");
                    w.WriteLine("</br>");
                    w.WriteLine("<div>");
                    w.WriteLine(txtDescription.Text);
                    w.WriteLine("</div>");
                    w.WriteLine("</div>");
                    w.WriteLine("</body></html>");
                    w.Dispose();
                }
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

// Encription && decription
//
public class EncryptionDecryption
    {

```
    public EncryptionDecryption()
    {
    }
    private static string keyString = "552F79D3-1F36-48ab-934C-4629C2274D43";
    private const string strTamperProofKey = "astkvsnanvpi";
    public static string TamperProofStringEncode(string strValue, string strKey)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES mac3des = new System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES();
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey));
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue)) + System.Convert.ToChar("-") + System.Convert.ToBase64String(mac3des.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strValue)));
    }

    public static string TamperProofStringDecode(string strValue, string strKey)
    {
        String strDataValue = "";
        String strCalcHash = "";
        strValue = strValue.Trim();
        strValue = strValue.Replace(" ", "+");

        System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES mac3des = new System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES();
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        mac3des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey));

        try
        {
            strDataValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(strValue.Split(System.Convert.ToChar("-"))[0]));

            strCalcHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mac3des.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strDataValue)));
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid TamperProofString");
        }
        return strDataValue;
    }
    public static string GetEncrypt(string value)
    {
        if (new HandleNull().CheckNull<string>(value).Trim().Length == 0) return value;
        return TamperProofStringEncode(value, strTamperProofKey);
    }
    public static string GetDecrypt(string value)
    {
        if (new HandleNull().CheckNull<string>(value).Trim().Length == 0) return value;
        return TamperProofStringDecode(value, strTamperProofKey);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This line's code then try it
    w.WriteLine("");

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
w.WriteLine("<img src='Images/" + ImageName + "' alt=" + fluImage.FileName + "  />");
```

You need to surround the `alt` value in quotes